# Want to create School Class time table in crystal report in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to show the time table of a teacher in a school e.g. a teacher teaches 8 periods(different subjects) in a day in 3 or 4 classes. I have created a crystal report using the "cross tab" expert in report vizard. I put "days of week" in column, "period no." in row and subject, class in the summary field of cross tab. 
So, generated crystal report have correct data in all fields as I wanted but there is below two problems-
1) There is one column of SUM of the rows and one for SUM columns. This should not show total.
2) Monday, Tuesday etc are not showing in correct order. Ho to correct its order.
I am attaching the screen shot of this.
Please help if someone knows about this problem.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: you can hide sum columns in tab expert, and the days order must be in original order i think crystal report put them in alphabethic order you can change in tab expert too.

Comment: Thanks I found there "Suppress row grand totals" and for column also. But I did not find there any way to change the days in alphabetical order.

Comment: In group options change what option do you have, may be you have asc order, there is an option "original order" then your source data must be ordered you want. You can chech this link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/493334/Custom-sorting-for-Crystal-Report-Cross-Tab also